# my for loop is creating bullet objects but not rendering them to the screen

Tags: javascript

i am creating a space invaders game, the tank and the aliens render to 
the screen, but the bullets wont render. also the web console is not 
showing any errors.

the bullets create objects and store them in a array. that is working 
when i console.log() it but it wont show the rect on the screen.

the web console is not showing any error either.

```js
    //this is in file helpers.js

    //create the bullets

    function Bullet(x, y, vely, w, h, color){
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.vely = vely;
      this.w = w;
      this.h = h;
      this.color = color;
    };

    Bullet.prototype.update = function() {
      this.y += this.vely;
    };

    SScreen.prototype.drawBullet = function(bullet){
      this.ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
      this.ctx.fillRect(bullet.x, bullet.y, bullet.width, bullet.height);
    }

    //this is in file main.js

    //this is in my update function

    if (input.isPressed(32)) {
        bullets.push(new Bullet(tank.x, tank.y, -8, 2, 6), "#FFF")
      };

    //this is in my render function

    scr.ctx.save();
    for (var i = 0, len = bullets.length; len < 0; i++) {
      scr.drawBullet([i]);
    }
scr.ctx.restore();
```

the result is that a rect apears near the tank when the space bar is presssed
but nothing apears

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on without knowing more about `SScreen`and such, but a couple of things look a bit funny to me at first glance. One is `bullets.push(new Bullet(tank.x, tank.y, -8, 2, 6), "#FFF"), which perhaps should be `bullets.push(new Bullet(tank.x, tank.y, -8, 2, 6, "#FFF"))`. The other is `for (var i = 0, len = bullets.length; len < 0; i++)`, where maybe `len < 0` should be `i < len`?

Comment: is there a way i can upload the source files or the folder so you can see exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to helpers SScreen function i added

```
this.canvas.color = this.color = color;
```

changed the Bullet function

```
SScreen.prototype.drawBullet = function(bullet){
  //this.beginPath();
  this.ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  this.ctx.fillRect(bullet.x, bullet.y, bullet.w, bullet.h);
  //this.closePath();
}
```

to main.js i changed the for loop to by adding array bullets[i] to the scr.DrawBullet

```
for (var i = 0, len = bullets.length; i < len; i++) {
  scr.drawBullet(bullets[i]);
```

and added a  red color to the screen variable

```
  scr = new SScreen(504, 600, 'red');
```

all credit goes to  AppleJam thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found some error here, hope this helps.

**1. Color property of Bullet object :**

```
if (input.isPressed(32)) {
   bullets.push(new Bullet(tank.x, tank.y, -8, 2, 6), "#FFF")
};
```

You didn't pass the `color` into `new Bullet`, so the color property became `undefined`.

Please try:

```
if (input.isPressed(32)) {
   bullets.push(new Bullet(tank.x, tank.y, -8, 2, 6,"#FFF"))
};
```

But I notice you don't need the bullet.color inside draw function, so you may ignore this part.

**2. Condition of for loop & parameter to pass into drawBullet :**

```
for (var i = 0, len = bullets.length; len < 0; i++) {
   scr.drawBullet([i]);
}
```

a. The condition is `len < 0`, it cause this for loop never get execute.

b. The bullet object is not pass into `drawBullet`

Please try:

```
for (var i = 0, len = bullets.length; i < len; i++) {
   scr.drawBullet(bullets[i]);
}
```

**3. w & h of Bullet object :**

```
SScreen.prototype.drawBullet = function(bullet){
  this.ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  this.ctx.fillRect(bullet.x, bullet.y, bullet.width, bullet.height);
}
```

The `bullet.width`,`bullet.height` does not exist.

Please try:

```
SScreen.prototype.drawBullet = function(bullet){
  this.ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  this.ctx.fillRect(bullet.x, bullet.y, bullet.w, bullet.h);
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying so fast i tried all your suggestions still nothing is working

Comment: i made a github thing, if you would like to look at my space invader folder to better understand what i have done. thank you. https://github.com/n-logic/fuzzy-afterlife-memory

Comment: I checked your code, and do the following to make bullets show : 1. in `main.js`, edited as the 2 part of my above answer. 2. in `helper.js`, defined a  `this.color` inside `SScreen` function.

Comment: still not working mate, did it work for you ??. i canged the loop like in your example, and i edited my helpers.js to                                                     function SScreen(width, height, color){
  this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  this.canvas.width = this.width = width;
  this.canvas.height = this.height = height;
  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
  this.color = color;

Comment: Yes, it work for me. Could you please update your repository so I can see the latest version?

Comment: i have updated the files , thank you for all the effort you have put in to help me. https://github.com/n-logic/fuzzy-afterlife-memory

Comment: You are welcome! I had send you a pull request, so you are able to see the code.

Comment: thank you i really appreciate all your help , it worked, but i don't understand why i have never had to declare a color when creating my screen before.

Comment: Actually I declare it here:https://github.com/n-logic/fuzzy-afterlife-memory/pull/1/files#diff-e206a2c2a6147e731b9b991e2968d366R7

see `scr = new SScreen(504, 600, 'red');`  I assigned red as default color.